# Python to calculate disk usage 1000 times of the du

Tags: python

I follow an instruction to calculate the disk usage:

```
import os
def disk_usage(path):
  """Return the number of bytes used by a file/folder and any descendents."""
  total = os.path.getsize(path)                  # account for direct usage
  if os.path.isdir(path):                        # if this is a directory,
    for filename in os.listdir(path):            # then for each child:
      childpath = os.path.join(path, filename)   # compose full path to child
      total += disk_usage(childpath)             # add child's usage to total

  print ('{0:<10}'.format(total), path)           # descriptive output (optional)
  return total                                   # return the grand total
```

Run it and get:

```
disk_usage("/Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo")    

117976604  /Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo
Out[117]: 117976604
```

However, when I utilize du

```
In [124]: !du -s /Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo                                                                  
125900  /Users/me/Desktop/PubRepo

   -s, --summarize
          display only a total for each argument



In [1]: 117976604 / 125900                                                                                      
Out[1]: 937.0659571088165
```

The python's result is about 1000 times.

What's the problem it might be?

Comment: `du` returns the number of units [in kilobytes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Du_(Unix)). `os.getsize()` returns [in bytes](https://docs.python.org/2/library/os.path.html#os.path.getsize).

Comment: how about the links, does it show the actual size of the link reference? @asongtoruin